# How to make a Discord bot delete its own message from a DM? (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am currently coding a Discord bot in Discord.js. I was wondering whether or not it is possible to make a bot delete its own message that it sent from a DM, and if so, what the code is. Using msg.delete() results in an error saying that you can't use that action on a DM. Thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, 'recipient' is the person you are sending a message to:

```
recipient.send("This is sent to your dm!").then(m => {
   m.delete(10000) //Deletes the message after 10000 milliseconds (10 seconds)
}
```

Next time, try and do a little research first. You can also read the docs for discord.js which likely do have this issue.